# Normalisation of data

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I am trying to plot the data below in a pie chart. I split the pie chart based on the group first and then based on the Id. But since for some rows, the count is very small, I am not able to see it in the pie chart.

I am trying to normalise the data. I am not sure on how to do that. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

```
 Group     Id      Count
 G1        12      276938
 G1        13      102
 G2        12      27
 G3        12      4683
 G3        13      7
 G4        12      301
```

Comment: You could try charting the log of the count. What's your end goal?

Comment: My end goal is to normalise the above data in a specific range.

Comment: what I mean is why do you want a pie chart?  any linear normalization won't change the size of the slices; did you try charting the log of the count?

Comment: Normalisation means scaling amounts measured with different scales. It doesn't apply to these data since they are measured on the same scale. A pie chart is not appropriate way of representing these data. Instead a bar-chart with a logarithmic scale is possible, but may be deceptive, or separate G1-12 from the others

Comment: @user2539738: No I have not tried it still. Is taking a log of count a normalisation technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pie chart what doesn't fit a visual representation in a pie chart

```
(
    df.groupby(['Group', 'Id'])
    .sum().Count.sort_values(ascending=False)
    .plot.bar(logy=True, subplots=True)
)
```